# How to solve coin change task when order does matters?

Tags: java, algorithm

As I found in [here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change),

Coin Change is the problem of finding the number of ways of making changes for a particular amount of cents, n, using a given set of denominations d_1....d_m. It is a general case of Integer Partition, and can be solved with dynamic programming.

The problem is typically asked as: If we want to make change for N cents, and we have infinite supply of each of S = { S_1, S_2,....., S_m } valued coins, how many ways can we make the change? **(For simplicity's sake, the order does not matter.)**

I tried this and this works fine. So How I can modify this to find all possible coin combinations when the **order of different coins actually does matter**.

i.e. : before

For example, for N = 4,S = {1,2,3}, there are four solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{2,2},{1,3}.

now :

for N = 4,S = {1,2,3}, there are 7 solutions: {1,1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,2,1},{2,1,1},{2,2},{1,3},{3,1}

here {1,1,1,1} even though one can pick the four '1's in different order it has to be considered as one final combination. rather than considering that four coins are different. so actually the order of different coins has to be different to count it as a separate combination.

ex: {1,1,3}  won't assume {1_a,1_b,3_a} is a combination and {1_b,1_a,3_a} is another combination with different ordering.

Comment: You could use your initial solution to generate the unique sets, and then generate all permutations of each set to generate all of the unique sequences.

Comment: Do you actually want to have all the solutions or just how many there are?

Comment: @Henry Both of them will work. I want to find the number. (as in the example it is 7 ). and It wont do harm if I can print those as well.

Comment: @mbeckish : yes. It is easy If I know the amount of different coin values and number of time they occur in the solution for each solution. But with the given algorithms in the link they will calculate only the answer (sum of different solutions). (not the different solutions one by one)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calculating just the number of solutions is much less effort than enumerating them all.

Lets take the example of S={1,2,3}, and call f(n) the number of solutions for amount n.

Then we have:

f(n) = 0 if n < 0

f(0) = 1

f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3) if n > 0  (where the numbers 1,2,3 are the elements of S)

It is not too difficult to write a program performing these calculations. You could start with the low numbers and work your way up:

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 2
f(3) = 4
f(4) = 7
f(5) = 13
...
```

For this specific S it turns out each number is just the sum of the preceding three numbers.

How to arrive at this formula? I take again the specific set S={1,2,3} as example, the general case is likewise easy. To count the number of solutions for n look at the first element. It can be 1, 2, or 3. If it is 1, there are f(n-1) ways to arrange the remaining elements. If it is 2 there are f(n-2) ways for the remaining elements and finally if it is 3 there are f(n-3) ways for the remaining elements. The total number must therefore be the sum of the three.

Comment: You're counting repeated values with this recursive solution. i.e. {2,2} and {2,2} should be 1 permutation not 2. Your method works only for distinct elements.

Comment: @wckd not true, if this were the case, the value for f(4) would not be correct.

Comment: Assuming this is correct what if S is dynamically assigned. we may not know S beforehand.

Comment: @wckd I don't think that's correct.  One of the terms used in computing f(4) is f(4-2), which basically counts all sequences beginning with 2 and followed by all sequences that add up to 2.  Since his count for f(2) didn't include the sequence {2} twice, I don't see how the count for f(4) includes {2,2} twice.

Comment: @prime I think he means f(n) = f(n-S_1) + f(n-S_2) + ... + f(n-S_m).  His last statement about "preceding three numbers" wouldn't apply in the general case.

Comment: @prime as ajb said, the formula for n>0 needs to be adapted to the concrete S.

Comment: @Henry does your equation hold for a larger set of S and is there a link to some sort of proof or derivation for this? Looking through it again it looks correct. My apologies.

Comment: @Henry am I correct saying that f(n) = sum( f(n-S[m]) ) for m = 0 < S.length 
Sorry for the use of different language types in that pseudocode.

Comment: I think for larger 'n' and larger S. this method cannot be implemented using a programming language. there might be a stack overflow ?

Comment: @prime You do not implement this with recursion. Instead, calculate the f(n) for n=0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... up to the N you are interested in. The space needed to store the smaller values is proportional to the largest element in S. So this should be quite efficient and no danger of a stack overflow.

Comment: So how can I calculate those f(n) for n=0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... up to the N I'm interested in without recursion ? surely I can't do it manually if N = 1000

Comment: @prime use an array `a` where `a[i-1]` holds the value f(n-i). To do the step to n+1 first calculate f(n+1), all required values are in the array `a` then shift the values in the array by one element and store f(n+1) in `a[0]`.

Comment: so you say "first calculate f(n+1)" , how do I do that ? manually ?

Comment: @prime I'd rather do that with a piece of code ;-) `sum=0; for(int i : S) { sum += a[i-1]; }`

Comment: it's how you got the pattern "For this specific S it turns out each number is just the sum of the preceding three numbers"

Comment: And in Java we can only use integer indexes in arrays. so this will bound N to max integer value. (without considering the memory). any way to overcome that. :)

Comment: Yes, in the general case the numbers to add depend on the set S.

Comment: and the previous one I ask can address using shifting I guess.

Comment: You do not need to store all smaller values just so many as the largest value in S. The smaller ones can be shifted out, they are no longer needed.

Comment: Yes I think this is a correct approach.I'll accept this one as the correct one :) (Y) Btw still we have a problem. What if n is very huge number. may be a Long type. N>10^20 or like that ? it will take too much time to process.

Comment: @prime if your looking at a HUGE number for N i.e. N > 10^20 you have other issues to worry about other than just runtime. Yes it will take a while because this algorithm is O(n) but because of the expansion of exponential growth (don't be fooled the solution does grow exponentially with increasing the values of n) you'd have to worry about how you store the number as long won't hold it. ( Java's long won't hold the value of N in your example either.)

Comment: @wckd yes you are correct.  Any solutions to that ? BigInteger type can use to hold  large numbers i think.

Comment: @prime BigInteger could work I really don't know where the cutoff would be for storing this number or how high you really want (or need) to go

Comment: FYI - If you want to calculate this for any N without caching or looping/recursion, there is a closed form solution - look up [tribonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers)

Comment: @mbeckish not only the special case but all linear homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients have a closed solution, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: @mbeckish thanks. But it is a very special situation. (i.e.  f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3) may not be for adding contiguous elements when it is like  f(n-1) + f(n-3) + f(n-4) )

Comment: @Henry I read that and I'm not very good at math. :/ Can you please guide me through that ?

Comment: @prime hmm, that would be much too long for a comment. Moreover, I don't think it is practical. The calculations to arrive at the formula involve finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial and doing a partial fraction expansion. The roots will typically be irrational or complex numbers and you would need very high precision floating point numbers (better than double) if you are interested in exact results for large N.

Comment: @Henry hmm. That's something then. I'll check more. Thanks for your massive support. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the "Dynamic programming" algorithm in the referenced Wikipedia page, I **think** you can just change

```
table[ i, j ] = table[ i - S_j, j ] + table[ i, j - 1 ]
```

to

```
table[ i, j ] = table[ i - S_j, m ] + table[ i, j - 1 ]
```

but I'm not 100% sure yet.  The point is that in the original problem, when you are examining coin S<sub>j</sub>, you want to add in the number of possible solutions when the amount is i - S<sub>j</sub> but only with coins up through S<sub>j</sub>, so that you don't get permutations of a previous sequence.  By changing it to `table[i - S_j, m]`, you do count the permutations.

**EDIT:** On looking into it further, I believe that this is correct but equivalent to Henry's answer, which is much simpler.  This version of the problem (counting all permutations) doesn't need values to be stored in a 2-D array, the way the original one does.

Comment: so with this approach will this hold ?
{1,1,3} won't assume {1_a,1_b,3_a} is a combination and {1_b,1_a,3_a} is another combination with different ordering

Comment: @prime If you're asking whether it will count {1,1,3} exactly once, I think so.  But I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm asking. it's a major concern. Thanks  for your answer. please contribute if you got a solution or please confirm this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The current recursive implementation is very simplified. It only passes the remaining value and the index of the possible denominations. If you passed an array of denominations when you got to n==0 you could add another check to see if you have that combination already. If you do return 0 otherwise return 1.

This is a dynamic solution and requires much more memory than the other solution but it will get you the answer.

```
func count(n, m, p[])
//regular if checks with additional nested if in (n == 0)
return count( n, m - 1, p[] ) + count( n - S[m], 0, p[] + S[m] )
```

in this pseudo code p[] + S[m] just means to add S[m] to the next available position in p[]

EDIT:

Forgot to add in that you need to reset m when you dive down

```
// n is remaining value
// m is index of S array
// p[] is array of coins used
// solutions[] is an array of p[] arrays
func count( n, m, p[]) {
  if n == 0
    if (p[] not in solutions[]){
      solutions[].add(p[])
      return 1
    }else{
      return 0
    }
  if n < 0
    return 0
  if m <= 0 and n >= 1
    return 0
  return count(n, m - 1, p[]) + count( n - S[m], 0, p[].add(S[m]))
}
```

By starting with an empty array p[] each time you add a coin to the possible set you append that value to the array. When you get to the point where you've found a solution you see if it's unique. If so you add it to the count otherwise you ignore it.
Because m is reset each time it will traverse all possible permutations.

Comment: can you please explain this approach more ?