# In how many ways can a change be made if the order in which the coins are paid matters?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am considering a variation of [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/) problem: given a list of denominations *S* and a change amount *n*, in how many ways can we make the change if the order in which the coins are paid matters?

For example, if `S = {1,2}` and `n = 4`, then the result should be `5`, as `(1,2,1)`, `(1,1,2)`, `(2,1,1)`, `(1,1,1,1)` and `(2,2)` are all possible solutions. Solving this where the order doesn't matter is easy, but I got stuck in this case.

Consider the code given [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/):

```cpp
int count( int S[], int m, int n )
{
    int i, j, x, y;

    // We need n+1 rows as the table is consturcted in bottom up manner using
    // the base case 0 value case (n = 0)
    int table[n+1][m];

    // Fill the enteries for 0 value case (n = 0)
    for (i=0; i<m; i++)
        table[0][i] = 1;

    // Fill rest of the table enteries in bottom up manner 
    for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            // Count of solutions including S[j]
            x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;

            // Count of solutions excluding S[j]
            y = (j >= 1)? table[i][j-1]: 0;

            // total count
            table[i][j] = x + y;
        }
    }

    return table[n][m-1];
}
```

When we have this line, `x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0`, how would I know how many solutions the addition of a new coin gives me?

Comment: Why don't you just do that as a post-processing step? Find all ways where order doesn't matter, and for each of those, find all permutations.

Comment: "Solving this where the order doesn't matter is easy, but I got stuck in this case." - Once you know the solution for the unordered case, just count each tuple by the number of permutations using the multinomial coefficient https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele: Thanks! As a matter of fact, that just popped into my mind as well.

Comment: The wrinkle may be that *counting* unordered solutions isn't the same as *finding* them.

Comment: his initial algorithm is about counting though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be closely related to the Fibonacci numbers. A solution is a very simple modification to the code given in my original post.

All that has to be done is have this line:

```
// Count of solutions including S[j]
x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][j]: 0;
```

changed to

```
// Count of solutions including S[j], but taking all "m" coins into account
x = (i-S[j] >= 0)? table[i - S[j]][m - 1]: 0;
```

This problem was apparently even [discussed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773103/how-to-solve-coin-change-task-when-order-does-matters) at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

**For just generating the number** : i refer to jpmath's comment.

**for learning DP sake only** :

easiest adaptation would be to extend the table with one dimension.

`table[i][j][k]` would then be whatever `table[i][j]` means (probably j = number coins and i = sum) with last coin being `k`.

in each step iterate through every `coin >= k` and add all necessary.

As dynamic programming always includes reasonable bounds it would be an easy adaptation with moderately slower running time. However as the Set S should be small either way it shouldnt be a problem.